BIRT on Tomcat9
Having problems integrating BIRT reports Runetime 4.17.0 on Tomcat9 at Windows Server 2016
I have followed all the instructions to install but it doesn't work.
I copied the folder 'webviewexample' and renamed as 'birt' the i download the commons-logging 1.3.4 and copied on the folder webinf/lib
I have modified the file catalina.bat Adding 'SET CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512 -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256'
I tryed to use the BIRT.war to add the folder automatically
When i oppen tomcat by local hots i can see the folder Buy if i try to Start shows an error 'Fail - application at context paty [/BIRT] could not be started
